# Запятые в уточняющем обороте

Tags: пунктуация

Как здесь правильно расставить знаки препинания? Это уточнение?

Некоторые производители в целях экономии используют для изготовления шаров такие стали, как 20Х13, 08Х18Н10 и другие более дешевые низколегированные стали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна, но это не уточнение. "Более дешёвые низко легированные стали" – вот уточнение.

Comment: Т.е. это однородные определения? Расставить надо так?
Некоторые производители в целях экономии используют для изготовления шаров такие стали, как 20Х13, 08Х18Н10 и другие, более дешевые низколегированные стали.

Comment: Нет, не однородные. Уточнение. Нельзя же сказать "другие и дешёвые".